# Xcode Crash Error

Tags: ios, xcode, crash

iOS devices are crashing when attempting to retrieve certain datasets.

Xcode log reads:

```
Warning>: Application 'EventsDev' exited abnormally with signal 6: Abort trap: 6.
```

What is Abort trap: 6 related to?

Comment: What version of xcode?

Answer (score 1):

To see where it crashed, create a new exception breakpoint, and set to 'all exceptions'.

Comment: That's a comment, not an answer ;)